# ABAQUS python script - define Element Type with viscosity properties

Tags: python

I have a ABAQUS script creating a 2D model, and everything is working as expected, except one thing. I have a cohesive layer where I use the COH2D4 element, whose properties on ABAQUS are the following:

Picture at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InT9c.png

The appropriate line I use in python to define this element is:

```
myPart.setElementType(regions=(myPart.faces[4],),elemTypes=(ElemType(elemCode=COH2D4,elemLibrary=STANDARD),))
```

So far so good. The problem is that the ABAQUS Scripting Reference Manual for the ElemType() function (section 30.3) enumerates several properties of the function, but none to control the Viscosity. This is necessary as I need to change this value to control convergence of the solution.

Any ideas how I can define this Viscosity parameter for the COH2D4 element? Thank you.

Running ABAQUS 6.11

### **Edit to post solution:**

The correct ElemType for this is:

```
ElemType(elemCode=COH2D4,elemLibrary=STANDARD,viscosity=<value>)
```

It seems obvious, but this is missing from the ABAQUS 6.11 documentation, although it works as expected. Found this reading the 6.12 documentation.

Comment: tip - create a macro in the gui to do what you want, then study the macro code to learn how to do things in your script.